# Strange numbers in lexer

Tags: c, lexer

I'm wrapping up my lexer and I'm having trouble printing and or correctly assigning numbers to their value. Here is my output, it should be `integer: "10"`, I believe the issue is somewhere around `lexer_num` or `lexer_flt`: 
(Including more information as requested.) I don't have or really know what a hex dump is so I don't think I can provide that. To answer your question about why `v` in `lexer_num` is a size_t is because their isn't a need for negative numbers since negative are handled in the parser not the lexer.

```
Type: "40" {
        Line: "1"
        Pos: "0"
        Num: "2591542"
        Real: "0.000000"
        Stri: ""
}
```

code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define DEBUG 0

#include "lexer.h"
#include "error.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct lextoken_t {
    const char* str;
    token_t type;
} lextoken_t;

static const lextoken_t keywords[] = {
    // types
    { "int", _int },
    { "double", _dbl },
    { "void", _void },
    { "char", _char },
    { "string", _str },
    { "bool", _bool },
    { "const", _const },
    { "struct", _struct }
};

/* token_new: creates and returns a new token ptr.
** -lexer: a ptr to the lexer.
** -type: the token type.
*/
token_t* token_new(lexer_t* lexer, tk_type type) {
    token_t* token = malloc(sizeof(token_t));
    token->line = lexer->line;
    token->pos = lexer->pos;
    token->type = type;
    token->integer = 0;
    token->flt = 0;
    token->string = NULL;

    return token;
}

static void token_print(token_t* token) {
    if (token == NULL)
        printf("Null token");

    printf("Type: \"%i\" { \n", token->type);
    printf("\tLine: \"%i\"\n", token->line);
    printf("\tPos: \"%i\"\n", token->pos);
    printf("\tNum: \"%i\"\n", token->integer);
    printf("\tReal: \"%f\"\n", token->flt);
    printf("\tStri: \"%s\"\n}\n\n", token->string);
}

/* lexer_look: look at the source (ahead) places infront of the lexer->ptr.
** -lexer: a ptr to the lexer to look ahead in.
** -ahead: how far ahead of the ptr to look.
*/
static char lexer_look(lexer_t* lexer, size_t ahead) {
    if (lexer->len < lexer->ptr + ahead) {
        error_new(lexer->errors, 0, 0, "The lexer tried to index %d out of bounds %d", lexer->ptr + ahead, lexer->len);
        return;
    }
    return lexer->src[lexer->ptr + ahead];
}

static size_t can_adv(lexer_t* lexer, size_t steps) {
    if (lexer->ptr + steps <= lexer->len)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

/* lexer_adv: moves the lexer->ptr (steps) places.
** -lexer: a ptr to the lexer to look ahead in.
** -steps: how far to advance the ptr.
*/
static char lexer_adv(lexer_t* lexer, size_t steps) {

    if (!can_adv(lexer, steps))
        error_new(lexer->errors, 0, 0, "The lexer tried to move ptr past bounds %d with value of %d", lexer->len, lexer->ptr + steps);
    lexer->ptr += steps;
    return lexer->src[lexer->ptr];
}

static void new_line(lexer_t* lexer) {
    lexer->line = 0;
    lexer->pos = 0;
}

static void lexer_nested(lexer_t* lexer) {
    lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
    char c = lexer_look(lexer, 0);
    size_t depth = 1;

    while (depth > 0) {
        if (!can_adv(lexer, 1))
            error_new(lexer->errors, lexer->line, lexer->pos, "Unterminated block comment.");
        else if (c == '*' && lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '#') {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
            depth--;
        } else if (c == '#' && lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '*') {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
            depth++;
        } else
            c = lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
    }
}

static void lexer_comment(lexer_t* lexer) {
    if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '*')
        lexer_nested(lexer);
    else {
        char c;
        while (((c = lexer_look(lexer, 0)) != '\n') && can_adv(lexer, 1))
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
        new_line(lexer);
    }
}

static token_t* lexer_str(lexer_t* lexer) {
    size_t str_len = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (!can_adv(lexer, 1)) {
            error_new(lexer->errors, lexer->len, lexer->pos, "Unterminated string.");
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '\"') {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
            break;
        }
        else {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            str_len++;
        }
    }

    char* string = malloc(str_len + 1);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < str_len; idx++)
        string[idx] = lexer->src[lexer->ptr - str_len + idx];
    string[str_len] = '\0';

    token_t* token = token_new(lexer, _str);
    token->string = string;
    return token;
}

static token_t* lexer_float(lexer_t* lexer, token_t* token, size_t v) {
    size_t places = 0;
    double d = v;

    if (!isdigit(lexer_look(lexer, 1))) { return token; }

    while (lexer->len > 0) {
        char c = lexer_look(lexer, 1);

        if (isdigit(c)) {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            d = (d * 10) + (c - '0');
            places++;
        } else
            break;
    }

    token->flt = d / (places * 10);
    token->string = "";
    return token;
}

static token_t* lexer_num(lexer_t* lexer) {
    token_t* token = token_new(lexer, _int);
    size_t v = 0;

    while (can_adv(lexer, 1)) {
        char c = lexer_look(lexer, 0);

        if (isdigit(c)) {
            v = (v * 10) + (c - '0');
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
        } else if (c == '.') {
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            return lexer_float(lexer, token, v);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    token->integer = v;
    token->string = "";
    return token;
}

static token_t* lexer_ident(lexer_t* lexer) {
    token_t* token = token_new(lexer, _ident);
    size_t id_len = 0;

    while (can_adv(lexer, 1)) {
        if (!isalpha(lexer_look(lexer, 0)))
            break;

        lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
        id_len++;
    }

    char* ident = malloc(id_len + 1);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < id_len; idx++)
        ident[idx] = lexer->src[lexer->ptr - id_len + idx];
    ident[id_len] = '\0';

    token->string = ident;
    return token;
}

static token_t* next_token(lexer_t* lexer) {
    token_t* token = NULL;

    while (token == NULL && can_adv(lexer, 1)) {
        const int c = lexer_look(lexer, 0);

        if (DEBUG)
            printf("Current character: \"%c\", Length: %d, Pointer: %d \n", lexer_look(lexer, 0), lexer->len, lexer->ptr);

        switch (c) {
        case '=':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _eqto);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "==";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _assign);
                token->string = "=";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '+':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _addeql);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "+=";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _add);
                token->string = "+";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '-':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _subeql);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "-=";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _sub);
                token->string = "-";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '*':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _muleql);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "*=";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _mul);
                token->string = "*";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '/':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _diveql);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "/=";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _div);
                token->string = "/";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '<':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '<') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _nteq);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "<=";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _bang);
                token->string = "<";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '>':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '<') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _nteq);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = ">=";
            }
            else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _bang);
                token->string = ">";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '&':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '&') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _and);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "&&";
            } else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _notype);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '|':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '|') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _or);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "||";
            }
            else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _notype);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '%':
            token = token_new(lexer, _mod);
            token->string = "%";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '^':
            token = token_new(lexer, _mod);
            token->string = "^";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '!':
            if (lexer_look(lexer, 1) == '=') {
                token = token_new(lexer, _nteq);
                lexer_adv(lexer, 2);
                token->string = "!=";
            }
            else {
                token = token_new(lexer, _bang);
                token->string = "!";
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            }

            break;
        case '\"':
            token = lexer_str(lexer);
            break;
        case '#':
            lexer_comment(lexer);
            break;
        case '(':
            token = token_new(lexer, _lpara);
            token->string = "(";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case ')':
            token = token_new(lexer, _rpara);
            token->string = ")";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '{':
            token = token_new(lexer, _lcurl);
            token->string = "{";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '}':
            token = token_new(lexer, _rcurl);
            token->string = "}";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case '[':
            token = token_new(lexer, _lbrac);
            token->string = "[";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case ']':
            token = token_new(lexer, _rbrac);
            token->string = "]";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        case ';':
            token = token_new(lexer, _terml);
            token->string = ";";
            lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if (isalpha(c) || c == '_')
                token = lexer_ident(lexer);
            else if (isdigit(c) || c == '.') {
                token = lexer_num(lexer);
            } else if (isspace(c))
                lexer_adv(lexer, 1);
            else
                token = token_new(lexer, _eof);

            break;
        }
    }

    return token;
}

void lexer_print(lexer_t* lexer) {
    size_t line = lexer->line;
    size_t pos = lexer->pos;
    size_t ptr = lexer->ptr;
    token_t* token = next_token(lexer);

    while (token != NULL && token->type != _eof) {
        token_print(token);
        token = next_token(lexer);
    }

    lexer->ptr = ptr;
    lexer->pos = pos;
}

lexer_t* lexer_open(const char* file_name) {
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    lexer_t* lexer = malloc(sizeof(lexer_t));
    lexer->errors = errorlist_new();
    lexer->line = 1;
    lexer->pos = 0;
    lexer->ptr = 0;

    if (file_ptr == NULL) {
        error_new(lexer->errors, 0, 0, "Couldent open file \"%s\".\n", file_name);
        fclose(file_ptr);
        free(lexer);
    }

    if (fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
        fclose(file_ptr);
        return NULL;
    }

    lexer->len = ftell(file_ptr);
    if (lexer->len == -1) {
        error_new(lexer->errors, 0, 0, "Unable to get the size of file \"%s\".\n", file_name);
        fclose(file_ptr);
        free(lexer);
    }
    fseek(file_ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    lexer->src = malloc(lexer->len);
    size_t r = fread(lexer->src, lexer->len, 1, file_ptr);
    fclose(file_ptr);
    return lexer;
}

void lexer_close(lexer_t* lexer) {
    if (lexer->src != NULL)
        free(lexer->src);

    free(lexer);
}
```

Header

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "error.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef enum tk_type {
    // primitives
    _notype,
    _str,
    _gen_num,
    _ident,
    _type,

    // symbols
    _rbrac,
    _lbrac,
    _rpara,
    _lpara,
    _rcurl,
    _lcurl,
    _terml,

    _assign,
    _bang,

    _add,
    _addeql,
    _sub,
    _subeql,
    _div,
    _diveql,
    _mul,
    _muleql,
    _exp,
    _mod,

    // comparison operators
    _lt,
    _lteq,
    _gt,
    _gteq,
    _eqto,
    _nteq,
    _and,
    _or,

    // keywords
    _while,
    _for,
    _if,
    _else,
    _match,
    _case,
    _return,
    _break,
    _int,
    _float,
    _enum,
    _true,
    _false,
    _import,
    _struct,
    _mac,
    _dbl,
    _void,
    _char,
    _bool,
    _const,

    // abstract
    _block,
    _eof
} tk_type;

typedef struct token_t {
    tk_type type;
    size_t line;
    size_t pos;

    union {
        char* string;
        double flt;
        size_t integer;
    };
} token_t;

typedef struct lexer_t {
    size_t line;
    size_t pos;
    size_t ptr;
    size_t len;
    char* src;

    errorlist_t* errors;
} lexer_t;

void lexer_print(lexer_t* lexer);

#endif
```

Input

```
int main() {
    int var = 10 + 2;
}
```

Comment: Information is  a bit sparse. What is your input (incl. hexdump, just in case), how is `token_t` defined and how do you print the output? The error can also hide in `can_adv()`, `lexer_look()`, `lexer_adv()`, and `token_new()`. Also: how is `lexer_t` defined and what is in it at the start of the function `lexer_num()`? And why is the data type of `v` a `size_t`?

Comment: Please review how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and update the question to provide one.  There's a decent chance the problem isn't in the code you currently show (and therefore is in the unshown code).  But since we can't run the code, we can't easily be sure.

Comment: I can assure you that the error IS in this code, but I will look over that. Thanks

Comment: Interesting so, this program would be a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" if anything, because this is about the seventh iteration of the program I've made.

Comment: `if (lexer->len < lexer->ptr + ahead) {` the off-by-one is still in there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem in `lexer_int` would seem to be at the end:

```
token->integer = v;
token->string = "";
```

Since `token_t` contains an anonymous union overlaying the `integer`, `flt` and `string` fields, this stores the number read, then immediately overwrites it with a pointer to the static string literal `""`.  You want to remove the `token->string = "";` line.

Of course, then your `token_print` routine will likely crash because it is trying to read the `string` field even when the token is not a string.

`lexer_float` has the same problem...

Comment: This is great help, thank you so much. It is working now, except for floats but that's a whole other issue I'll solve once I get more sleep. :)